# change app name in eclipse without creation new Project in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am new in sencha,
I have design one app and deployed on tablet using eclipse.
I want to change APP name without creating new Eclipse project.
How should I do that. Please provide steps.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this steps -

go to res file -> values -> strings.xml....

MitsuhoSdn Bhd
Hello world!
Settings

Answer (score 1):

Select the project and then there is this key shortcut:

```
Alt + Shift + R
```

There you can rename your project and it will update all the other related files.